# Assignment operators in a class deriving boost::units::quantity

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost-units

I have a problem with the assignment operators. Please have a look at my code below:

```
template<typename PARAM_TYPE,      typename DATA_TYPE>
class Parameter : public boost::units::quantity<PARAM_TYPE, DATA_TYPE>
{
public:
Parameter<PARAM_TYPE, DATA_TYPE> & operator = ( const quantity<PARAM_TYPE, DATA_TYPE> & Q )
{
    // ...
}

Parameter<PARAM_TYPE, DATA_TYPE> & operator = ( const Parameter<PARAM_TYPE, DATA_TYPE> & P )
{
    // ... do something more than in assignment operator taking quantity
}
};
```

My problem is when working with Parameter class instances. As you may know the `boost::units::quantity` manipulates physical units of the variable. Therefore I have to use all the operators coming from `boost::units::quantity`. As a result of such operation is quantity again. For example:

```
Parameter<si::length> P;
quantity<si::length> Q1( 1.0 * si::meter );
quantity<si::length> Q2 ( 1.0 * si::meter );

P = Q1 + Q2;
```

So far so good, assignment operator taking quantity is used. The problem comes when doing quite similar thing:

```
Parameter<si::length> P;
Parameter<si::length> P1( 1.0 * si::meter );
Parameter<si::length> P2 ( 1.0 * si::meter );

P = P1 + P2;
```

As `Parameter<>` is derived from `quantity<>` it seems an assignment operator taking quantity as argument is used either!

QUESTION: is there a way to force compiler to use assignment operator taking `Parameter<>` as argument while using `quantity<>:: operator +` in the second case?

Many thanks in advance to anyone willing to help. Cheers Martin